# Laptop not booting after fresh ubuntu mate 15 install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I just installed Ubuntu Mate 15 onto my laptop. After a successful install, I can't seem to boot into the OS. There's a blinking cursor on the screen and that's it. I used a LiveCD to try repairing it using boot repair but that also didn't help. Also tried disabling SecureBoot in BIOS: There wasn't any option like that in my BIOS.

The boot repair report is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15585301/.

I'm new to Linux so I'm not sure what I might be doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem you are facing is the missing bootloader.

```
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.
```

Soution 1:

It seems there are parts of old installations of windows and osx on your system, a clean and simple solution is to reinstall ubuntu mate and create a new partition layout for one of the two harddrives via the installation wizard. Also I cant see any data partition formated in ext4 (default option).

Solution 2:
(does not apply to you but to majority with this problem)

Boot your system with a live-cd (maybe your mate install medium) and install grub with the following commands:

Show drive and partition info:

```
sudo parted -l
```

Mount system and boot partition:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/boot
```

/dev/sdX is (in this case) either the drive sda or sdb, /dev/sdXY is pointing to the partition (/dev/sda1, /dev/sdb2, ...), make sure which drive contains your system and boot partition and check the bios boot options and correct them if they do not point to the correct device.

Mount your drive installed system:

```
for dir in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount --bind $dir /mnt/$dir; done && sudo mount -o bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

chroot into your system:

```
sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash
```

Reinstall grub:

```
apt-get update
apt-get --reinstall install grub-common grub-pc os-prober # grub-gfxpayload-lists
grub-setup /dev/sdX
```

Grub will be installed to the MBR of the selected drive.
Trigger a reboot, if your boot options point to the drive you instal bootled grub at, a bootloader should pop up at boot.